# Running C# program compiled with Mono in Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I've compiled a simple helloworld program with Mono in Ubuntu, which I can execute using,

> mono helloworld.exe

Also, I could just say,

> helloworld.exe

and it works. However, in a different Linux machine where I had to build Mono from source (unlike with Ubuntu's already available package), the latter command does not work. It gives me the error,

> -bash: ./helloworld.exe: cannot execute binary file

Any suggestions?

Thank you,

Comment: Perhaps it has been linked with a different libc.so, etc..

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to register the non-native executable format, for a more detailed explanation please look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20246/running-a-mono-program-without-typing-in-mono-foo-exe)